# Should I change my default python version to the latest python version?

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, python-3.5

I have Python 2.7.9 by default on my system :-

```
amitwebhero@AmitKali:~$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

And I have installed its latest version Python 3.5.

```
amitwebhero@AmitKali:~$ python3.5
Python 3.5.0+ (default, Oct 11 2015, 09:05:38) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151003] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But whenever i want to compile a python program in terminal then i need to write `python3.5 file_name.py` , so i was thinking to change my default python version.

But I have installed my plugins and program based on python 2.7.9, so I have doubt that if I make my python 3.5 to default then it may cause problems to all those plugins which I installed using previous version of python.

If possible try tell should I change my default python or not?

Comment: Before we answer your question: Do you know the deference between these two versions?

Comment: @KevinGuan yes... I know

Comment: So if you really want to do that, then maybe lots of programs will not work if they write the *shebang* like `.../python`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it depends on the operating system. For windows - maybe you can. There should be no much dependencies on Python there.

But I suppose that you run linux-based os.

For centos, for example, you may break `yum` package manager - as far as I know it depends on Python2 still. Ubuntu has a lot of packages depending on P2 too despite of they're planning to move to P3 starting from 16.04.

To make your work convenient you may add the following line as the very first line of your `.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Make your `.py` file executable: `chmod a+x` and you can simply run it without interpreter name.